# Numeric values from list do not get matched properly in lapply function in R?

Tags: r, lapply

I refer to stack overflow for quite a bit, but this is my first post.

I am trying to match a list of references (from a age/gender normalized table) to scored values. 
I generated list of references and matched to the scored values with the codes below:

```
#generate a simple dataframe
df<- data.frame("var1" = c(1,3,5,1))

#generate a list of raw values
n5<- seq(-16, -7.3, by=0.01)
n45<- seq(-7.29, -6.3, by = 0.01)
n4<- seq(-6.29, -5.2, by = 0.01)
n35<- seq(-5.19, -4.2, by = 0.01)
n3<- seq(-4.19, -3.2, by = 0.01)
n25<- seq(-3.19, -2.2, by = 0.01)
n2<- seq(-2.19, -1.1, by = 0.01)
n15<- seq(-1.09,-0.01, by = 0.01)
n1<- seq(0, 0.9, by = 0.01)
n05<- seq(0.91, 2, by = 0.01)
p0<- seq(2.01, 3, by = 0.01)
p05<- seq(3.01, 4, by = 0.01)
p1<- seq(4.01,5.1, by = 0.01)
p15<- seq(5.11, 6.1, by = 0.01)
p2<- seq(6.11,7.1, by = 0.01)
p25<- seq(7.11,8.2, by = 0.01)
p3<- seq(8.21, 9.2, by = 0.01)
p35<- seq(9.21, 10.2, by = 0.01)
p4<- seq(10.21, 11.2, by = 0.01)
p45<- seq(11.21,12.3, by = 0.01)
p5<- seq(12.31,16, by = 0.01)

#generate a list of standard scores
m1 <- list(
  c(-5, n5),
  c(-4.5, n45),
  c(-4,n4),
  c(-3.5,n35),
  c(-3, n3),
  c(-2.5, n25 ),
  c(-2, n2),
  c(-1.5,n15),
  c(-1,n1),
  c(-0.5,n05),
  c(0,p0),
  c(0.5, p05),
  c(1, p1),
  c(1.5,p15),
  c(2,p2),
  c(2.5, p25),
  c(3, p3),
  c(3.5, p35),
  c(4, p4),
  c(4.5, p45),
  c(5, p5))


#matching
lapply(m1, function(x) {
  df$std_var1[df$var1 %in% x] <<- x[[1]]})
#duplicates the original value instead of matching


#forced number of digits from 0 to 2; matches with NA
df$var1r<-sprintf("%0.2f", df$var)

lapply(m1, function(x) {
  df$std_var1r[df$var1r %in% x] <<- x[[1]]})
```

Although this approach worked for most of variables I have, the same code simply duplicates the original values for few variables instead of matching it based on the reference list I generated. I tried to change digits and numeric formats, but I cannot figure out why the code works for some and does not work for other variables. Any alternative approach would be much appreciated.

Here's a screenshot of the table. Matched values were written for your reference.
The first and second columns are the same with different digits. The third column is the standardized number that suppose to be matched, but duplicated original values instead of replacing with matched values.

Screenshot of df:
EDIT: REMOVED Screenshot

UPDATED (06/15/20):

Please see below for a table for your reference (original - original value; actual - actual matched result; expected - expected matched result)

```
*Original  | Actual  | Expected   |*
 1         |   1     |   -0.5
 3         |   3     |    0
 5         |   5     |    1
 1         |   1     |   -0.5
```

The same approach works well with expected matched result if the original values have digits. Please see code below:

```
#generate a simple dataframe
df.2<- data.frame("var2" = c(1.40, 1.52, 3.21, 5.10))


#subject cluster bidirectional chance adjusted

n3<- seq(-1.90, -1.50, by = 0.001)
n25<- seq(-1.49, -1.10, by = 0.001)
n2<- seq(-1.09, -0.70, by = 0.001)
n15<- seq(-0.69, -0.30, by = 0.001)
n1<- seq(-0.29, 0.10, by = 0.001)
n05<- seq(0.11, 0.60, by = 0.001)
p0<- seq(0.61, 1.00, by = 0.001)
p05<- seq(1.01, 1.40, by = 0.001)
p1<- seq(1.41, 1.80, by = 0.001)
p15<- seq(1.81, 2.20, by = 0.001)
p2<- seq(2.21,2.6, by = 0.001)
p25<- seq(2.61, 3.1, by = 0.001)
p3<- seq(3.11, 3.5, by = 0.001)
p35<- seq(3.51, 3.9, by = 0.001)
p4<- seq(3.91, 4.3, by = 0.001)
p45<- seq(4.4,4.7, by = 0.001)
p5<- seq(4.71,14.1, by = 0.001)

##
m2 <- list(
  c("-3",n3),
  c("-2.5", n25),
  c("-2",n2),
  c("-1.5", n15),
  c("-1", n1),
  c("-0.5", n05),
  c("0", p0),
  c("0.5", p05),
  c("1", p1),
  c("1.5", p15),
  c("2", p2),
  c("2.5", p25),
  c("3", p3),
  c("3.5",p35),
  c("4",p4),
  c("4.5", p45),
  c("5", p5))

#sub clust bi chance adj (t1-5)
lapply(m2, function(x) {
  df.2$std_var2r[df.2$var2 %in% x] <<- x[[1]]})

#matching worked

#var2    std_var2r
#1.40     0.5
#1.52     1
#3.21     3
#5.10     5
```

One of the responses suggested that I may have a floater problem, but I can't seem to find a solution. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you have floating point numbers

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! For getting good answers, I would suggest making a simplified working example to illustrate your point and what you want to achieve. It's a bit hard to follow the question here with really long names and a screenshot of the expected output..

Comment: Thank you for a quick response @akrun and Gautam. I think floating point numbers may be the right diagnosis of the problem. I am going to see if I can resolve it.

Comment: Dear @Gautam, I have edited working example to illustrate the problem I am having. Any guidance or support would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'missing what you want to obtain, but when you match `df$std_var1[df$var1 %in% x] <<- x[[1]]` into lapply, only last matching to the element of list m1 term will survive, because last x[[1]] will overwrite previous one. Let's see `df$var1 %in% x`:

```
> lapply(m1, function(x) {
+   df1$var1 %in% x})
[[1]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[4]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[5]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[6]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[7]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[8]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[9]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[10]]
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

[[11]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

[[12]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[13]]
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

[[14]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[15]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[16]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[17]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

[[18]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[19]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[20]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[21]]
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

`[[13]]` presented the last TRUE for first and fourth elements of the new column `std_var1` you are creating into df, since `m1[[13]]` is `c(1, p1)` therefore `x[[1]] = 1` and this 1 is assigned to rows 1 and 4 of df$std_var1. The last TRUE for the 2nd position occurs when x = m1[[17]] and for 3rd position when x = m1[[21]], which are `c(3, p3)` and `c(3, p5)`, therefore x[[1]] is 3 and 5 respectively, thus giving 'df$std_var1 = c(1,3,5,1).
So the code does not work as you expected, but I can't figure out what is the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your response and support. I have updated my original post with the expected result. The x[[1]] is correct, because I am replacing a list of raw values to a standardized value, which is assigned to the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the problem. If I changed the match to exclude the first value in the vector it worked OK.

Old: 
lapply(m1, function(x) {
  df$std_var1[df$var1 %in% x] <<- x[[1]]})

New: 
lapply(m1, function(x) {
  df$std_var1[df$var1 %in% x[-1]] <<- x[[1]]})